# How to manipulate an ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I made a simple code so I could manipulate the coefficients of ordinary differential equations but it's not working correctly. Can anyone help me?

```
sol1 = DSolveValue[{a*y''[x] - b*y'[x] + c*y[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0, 
   y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]

Manipulate[Plot[sol1, {x, 0, 10}], {a, -3, 3}, {b, -3, 3}, {c, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: Note that the `DSolveValue` solution is invalid if `b^2 - 4 a c == 0`, e.g., for `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 1`.  You could use `Limit` instead of directly plugging in, but it's rather too slow for `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, actually. Your first attempt will work if you `With` the solution into the `Manipulate`:

```
With[{sol = Simplify[sol1]},
  Manipulate[
    Plot[sol, {x, 0, 10}],
    {a, -3, 3},
    {b, -3, 3},
    {c, -3, 3}
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sol[a_, b_, c_] := 
NDSolve[{
a*y''[x] - b*y'[x] + c*y[x] == Sin[x],
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0},
y, {x, 0, 10}]

Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[a, b, c]], {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}],
{{a, 1, "a"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{b, 1, "b"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c, 1, "c"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Solution by `DSolve`:

```
 sol2 = First@
 DSolve[{a*y''[x] - b*y'[x] + c*y[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0, 
 y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
 SOL[a_, b_, c_] := Evaluate[y[x] /. sol2]
 Manipulate[
 Plot[SOL[a, b, c], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}], {{a, 1, "a"}, -3, 3, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1, "b"}, -3, 3, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, 1, "c"}, -3, 3, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it need to be NDSolve ?

Comment: @user57225. Symbolic solution its better 
because is faster.If `DSolve` can't solve equation symbolically  use `NDSolve`

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an analytical solution, but avoid having to solve the ODE each time you change the slides, you can solve the ODE once, and do replacement. Something like

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Item[sol /. {a0 -> a, b0 -> b, c0 -> c}, ItemSize -> 40]},
   {Plot[Evaluate[sol /. {a0 -> a, b0 -> b, c0 -> c}], {x, 0, 10}, 
     ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"y(x)", None}, {"x", "my solution"}},
     GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
     PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> 14
     ]
    }}],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, -3, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1, "b"}, -3, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 1, "c"}, -3, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (
   ode = a0*y''[x] - b0*y'[x] + c0*y[x] == Sin[x];
   ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
   sol = y[x] /. DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x];
   )
 ]
```

You can do more improvements as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a*y''[x] - b*y'[x] + c*y[x] == Sin[x], 
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 10}, {a, b, c}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[psol[a, b, c][x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1, "b"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 1, "c"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) calls `NDSolve` for a given input `a, b, c`, it saves and reuses the result if the parameters do not change.  This means that the differential equation is solved only once when the parameters are changed.